# Vimeo Embed Video 'Because of its privacy settings, this video cannot be played here'

Tags: html, ajax, vimeo

I am trying to embed my client videos in our website. The videos are set to domain level privacy. I am using the generated code from Vimeo

```
<div style="padding:28% 0 0 0;position:relative;">
      <iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/{{video_id}}" style="position:absolute;top:0;left:0;width:100%;height:100%;" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen ></iframe>
    </div>
```

where ```{{video_id}}`` is the id of the video. I have followed all the documentation and made sure that the listed domain is spelled correctly.

I am getting:

Sorry

Because of its privacy settings, this video cannot be played here.

Why? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Perhaps this is an issue with your hosting account?  Where is the site hosted?

Comment: digital ocean. My code is in django. My client and I have submitted a ticked to DO and Vimeo. DO said it is a Vimeo issue, and Vimeo is being really slow in helping us. Origanally, we were using a different link to the videos, and everything worked, expect on apple devices, and Vimeo said to user the embedded code that was generated.

Comment: EDIT: I have edit the link [link](src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/{{video_id}}?h={{hash}}") We are still getting this error. Why?

Comment: _set to domain level privacy_. What other choices are there?  Could this be a Vimeo setting?

Comment: Post a screenshot with your video privacy screen. Check your video is not in any sort of wrapping iframe. Check your cookies are not blocked (using any browser extensions, like adblockers).

Comment: @Watson Did you get any solution?

Answer (score 4):

Here is the [issue](https://vimeo.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/115015677227-Troubleshoot-player-error-messages):

That is request of iframe in django page, (particularly, ones are under proxy server), does not have http_referer or its value does not match the domain which has been set for the video on vimeo.

I have figured out. Just add this attribute to iframe tag and it works:

```
<iframe ...referrerpolicy="strict-origin"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you got it. Apparently there was a change w/ Django 3.1 that causes this.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/releases/3.1/#security

You can fix it with a Django setting. This is one option, but any of the valid referrer policies that share the origin with Vimeo will work.

```
SECURE_REFERRER_POLICY = "strict-origin-when-cross-origin"
```